# Inheriting the android:tint attribute from a ViewGroup

Tags: android, android-layout

**If the `android:tint` attribute is set for a `ViewGroup`, should it apply to all descendant `View`'s, or does it need to be applied to each individually?**

The `LinearLayout` below (`ButtonBar$LabeledButton`) contains an `ImageView` and `TextView` that each specify their own color state list (`CSL`).

I'd like to set `android:tint` once in the `ViewGroup` so when it is disabled, all its members become disabled and change their tint accordingly (and also without having to override the `setEnabled`).

**resources/layout/buttonbar_labeledbutton_addnew.axml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--LinearLayout-->
<view class="ButtonBar$LabeledButton"
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/ButtonBar_LabeledButton_AddNew"
  style="@style/ButtonBar_LabeledButton">

  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ButtonBar_LabeledButton_Image"
    style="@style/ButtonBar_LabeledButton_Image"
    android:src="@drawable/v__ic_add_circle_outline_black_24dp"/>

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/ButtonBar_LabeledButton_Label"
    style="@style/ButtonBar_LabeledButton_Label"
    android:text="Add New"/>

</view>
<!--/LinearLayout-->
```

**resources/values/styles.xml**

```
  <!--LinearLayout-->
  <style name="ButtonBar_LabeledButton">
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:orientation">horizontal</item>
    <??-item name="android:tint">@color/buttonbar_csl</item-??>
  </style>

  <!--ImageView-->
  <style name="ButtonBar_LabeledButton_Image">
    <item name="android:layout_width">40dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">40dp</item>
    <item name="android:tint">@color/buttonbar_csl</item>
  </style>

   <!--TextView-->
  <style name="ButtonBar_LabeledButton_Label">
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/buttonbar_csl</item>
    <!--item name="android:tint">@color/buttonbar_csl</item-->
  </style>
```

**ButtonBar.LabeledButton**

```
[Register("ButtonBar$LabeledButton")]
public class LabeledButton : LinearLayout
{
    public LabeledButton(Context context, IAttributeSet attributes) : base(context, attributes) { }

    public override bool Enabled
    {
        set
        {
            var image = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.ButtonBar_LabeledButton_Image);
            if( image != null )
                image.Enabled = value;

            var label = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.ButtonBar_LabeledButton_Label);
            if( label != null )
                label.Enabled = value;

            base.Enabled = value;
        }
    }    
}
```

---

**Update**

> [**Attributes**](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html#attributes)
>
> Every View and ViewGroup object supports their own variety of XML
>   attributes. Some attributes are specific to a View object (for
>   example, TextView supports the textSize attribute), but these
>   attributes are also inherited by any View objects that may extend this
>   class. Some are common to all View objects, because they are inherited
>   from the root View class (like the id attribute). And, other
>   attributes are considered "layout parameters," which are attributes
>   that describe certain layout orientations of the View object, as
>   defined by that object's parent ViewGroup object.

`android:tint` is specific to `ImageView`, and is ignored. I didn't inspect the attribute set in `ButtonBar$LabeledButton`'s inflation constructor to see if it is at lest present to work with.  Declaring a custom attribute would solve this, but then it's assignment to the `ImageView` and `TextView` in their now required custom classes' inflation constructors would be obscured (I prefer to leverage the framework as much as possible to minimize any extra, one-off code b/c of the maintenance and potential point-of-failure it introduces).

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html#attributes

Answer (score 0):

**ButtonBar**

```
public class ButtonBar : LinearLayout
{
    public ButtonBar(Context context, IAttributeSet attributes) : base(context, attributes) { }

    public override bool Enabled
    {
        set
        {
            SetChilderenEnabled(value);

            base.Enabled = value;
        }
    }

    private void SetChilderenEnabled(bool value)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < ChildCount; i++)
        {
            GetChildAt(i).Enabled = value;
        }
    }

    [Register("us.sam.views.ButtonBar$LabeledButton")]
    public class LabeledButton : LinearLayout
    {
        private ImageView _buttonIV;
        private TextView _labelTV;
        private int _buttonIV_src;
        private string _labelTV_text;

        public override bool Enabled
        {
            set
            {
                if (_buttonIV != null)
                    _buttonIV.Enabled = value;

                if (_labelTV != null)
                    _labelTV.Enabled = value;

                base.Enabled = value;
            }
        }

        public LabeledButton(Context context, IAttributeSet attributes) : base(context, attributes)
        {
            ReadAttributes(context, attributes);

            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.From(context);

            _labelTV = (TextView)inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.ButtonBar_LabeledButton_LabelTextView, this, false);
            _buttonIV = (ImageView)inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.ButtonBar_LabeledButton_ButtonImageView, this, false);

            _labelTV.Text = _labelTV_text;
            _buttonIV.SetImageResource(_buttonIV_src);

            AddViewInLayout(_buttonIV, ChildCount, _buttonIV.LayoutParameters);
            AddViewInLayout(_labelTV, ChildCount, _labelTV.LayoutParameters);
        }

        private void ReadAttributes(Context context, IAttributeSet attributes)
        {
            Android.Content.Res.TypedArray typedArray = context.ObtainStyledAttributes(attributes, Resource.Styleable.LabeledButton);

            _buttonIV_src = typedArray.GetResourceId(Resource.Styleable.LabeledButton_button_imageview_src, 0);
            _labelTV_text = typedArray.GetString(Resource.Styleable.LabeledButton_label_textview_text);

            typedArray.Recycle();
        }
    }
}
```

**recordexpandablelistview_groupbuttonbar_trecords.axml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--LinearLayout-->
<view class="us.sam.RecordsView$RecordExpandableListView$GroupButtonBar"
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
  android:id="@+id/RecordExpandableListView_GroupButtonBar_TRecords"
  style="@style/RecordExpandableListView_GroupButtonBar">

  <!--LinearLayout-->
  <us.sam.Views.ButtonBar
    android:id="@+id/ButtonBar"
    style="@style/ButtonBar">

    <include layout="@layout/ButtonBar_LabeledButton_AddNew"/>

  </us.sam.Views.ButtonBar>

  <ImageView style="@style/ListItem_Divider_Horizontal"/>

</view>
```

**ButtonBar_LabeledButton_AddNew.axml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--LinearLayout-->
<view class="us.sam.views.ButtonBar$LabeledButton"
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
  android:id="@+id/ButtonBar_LabeledButton_AddNew"
  style="@style/ButtonBar_LabeledButton"
  button_imageview_src="@drawable/v__ic_add_circle_outline_black_24dp"
  label_textview_text="@string/ButtonBar_LabeledButton_LabelTextView_Text_AddNew">
</view>
```

**ButtonBar_LabeledButton_ButtonImageView.axml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--<view class="us.sam.views.ButtonBar$LabeledButton$Button"-->
<ImageView
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/ButtonBar_LabeledButton_ButtonImageView"
  style="@style/ButtonBar_LabeledButton_ButtonImageView"/>
<!--android:src="@drawable/v__ic_add_circle_outline_black_24dp"-->
```

**ButtonBar_LabeledButton_LabelTextView.axml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--view class="us.sam.views.ButtonBar$LabeledButton$Label"-->
<TextView
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/ButtonBar_LabeledButton_LabelTextView"
  style="@style/ButtonBar_LabeledButton_LabelTextView"/>
<!--android:text="Add New"-->
```

**styles.xml**

```
  <!--LinearLayout-->
  <style name="RecordExpandableListView_GroupButtonBar">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:orientation">vertical</item>
    <!--use isChildSelectable() override in BaseExpandableListAdapter instead-->
    <!--item name="android:clickable">true</item-->
  </style>

  <!--LinearLayout-->
  <style name="ButtonBar">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:orientation">horizontal</item>
  </style>

  <!--LinearLayout-->
  <style name="ButtonBar_LabeledButton">
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:orientation">horizontal</item>    
  </style>

    <!--ImageView-->
  <style name="ButtonBar_LabeledButton_ButtonImageView">
    <item name="android:layout_width">40dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">40dp</item>    
    <item name="android:tint">@color/button_bar_csl</item>    
  </style>

  <!--TextView-->
  <style name="ButtonBar_LabeledButton_LabelTextView">
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_gravity">center_vertical</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center_vertical</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>    
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/button_bar_csl</item>    
  </style>

  <style name="ListItem_Divider_Horizontal">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">1px</item>
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/black</item>
  </style>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49076244/inflating-a-merged-layout-using-onfinishinflate