# Inflating a merged layout using onFinishInflate

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a view that is used as a list element so am striving for optimal inflation performance.

In `OnFinishInflate()`, an `ImageView` and `TextView` are assigned their content (a drawable and a string) and even though this seems to work as expected, I'm uncertain if there is a better way?

It seems like `onLayout` may be more appropriate b/c the `TextView`'s `width` and `height` are set to *`wrap_content`*, and so assigning the *`text`* after inflation would trigger `onMeasure` and `onLayout` passes, causing twice the amount of work (assuming `onFinishInflate` happens after them).

**ButtonBar_LabeledButton_AddNew.axml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--LinearLayout-->
<view class="us.sam.views.ButtonBar$LabeledButton"
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
  android:id="@+id/ButtonBar_LabeledButton_AddNew"
  style="@style/ButtonBar_LabeledButton"
  button_imageview_src="@drawable/v__ic_add_circle_outline_black_24dp"
  label_textview_text="@string/ButtonBar_LabeledButton_LabelTextView_Text_AddNew">  

  <include layout="@layout/ButtonBar_LabeledButton_merge"/>

</view>
```

**ButtonBar_LabeledButton_merge.axml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <!--<view class="us.sam.views.ButtonBar$LabeledButton$Button"-->
  <ImageView  
    android:id="@+id/ButtonBar_LabeledButton_ButtonImageView"
    style="@style/ButtonBar_LabeledButton_ButtonImageView"/>
  <!--android:src="@drawable/v__ic_add_circle_outline_black_24dp"-->

  <!--view class="us.sam.views.ButtonBar$LabeledButton$Label"-->
  <TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ButtonBar_LabeledButton_LabelTextView"
    style="@style/ButtonBar_LabeledButton_LabelTextView"/>
  <!--android:text="Add New"-->

</merge>
```

**LabeledButton**

```
public class LabeledButton : LinearLayout
{
    private ImageView _buttonIV;
    private TextView _labelTV;
    private int _buttonIV_src;
    private string _labelTV_text;

    public LabeledButton(Context context, IAttributeSet attributes) : base(context, attributes)
    {
        ReadAttributes(context, attributes);                
    }

    private void ReadAttributes(Context context, IAttributeSet attributes)
    {
        Android.Content.Res.TypedArray typedArray = context.ObtainStyledAttributes(attributes, Resource.Styleable.LabeledButton);

        _buttonIV_src = typedArray.GetResourceId(Resource.Styleable.LabeledButton_button_imageview_src, 0);
        _labelTV_text = typedArray.GetString(Resource.Styleable.LabeledButton_label_textview_text);

        typedArray.Recycle();
    }

    protected override void OnFinishInflate()
    {
        base.OnFinishInflate();

        _buttonIV = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.ButtonBar_LabeledButton_ButtonImageView);
        _labelTV = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.ButtonBar_LabeledButton_LabelTextView);

        _buttonIV.SetImageResource(_buttonIV_src);
        _labelTV.Text = _labelTV_text;
    }
}
```

Comment: why dont you use `LayoutInflater` directly?

Comment: @pskink I was [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49075035/1105214), but figured it'd be more efficient to not explicitly call the inflater (twice). Plus, I think the `include` is more readable (doesn't obscure the internal widgets).

Comment: ok so you need it for `ListView` / `RecyclerView` optimization? if so, you will only create your `LabeledButton` ten times (or so) at most, so why to bother with couple of ms?

Comment: @pskink I think `merge`/ `include` is more explicit. Are there other reasons why I should be avoiding?

Comment: no, you can use them at will, the question is what you want to achieve with that little optimization? after all you will create less then dozen `LabeledButton`s...

Comment: @pskink I'm not sure if I should be assigning the drawable and string after the inflation, or during the layout. Will `_labelTV.Text = _labelTV_text;" cause another `onLayout` pass? Does `onFinishInflate` usually get called before or after `onLayout`? Should I be assigning in `onLayout`, or maybe somewhere else besides `onFinishInflate` (I've been reading the source, and will be stepping through it as soon as I get everything setup on home computer).

Comment: refer to `LayoutInflater` sources to see when it calls `parent.onFinishInflate()` - it is at the end of `rInflate` method- but again, WHY to bother if you dont want to create 1000s `LabeledButton`s ???

Comment: @pskink Ok, will check it out... I like the verbosity of the `include` statement. Without it, `LabeldButton`'s children widgets (`ImageView`, `TextView`) are obscured - one would never know by looking at **ButtonBar_LabeledButton_AddNew.axml** that it has children unless the `include` is present (which explicitly references  `ButtonBar_LabeledButton_merge.axml`). Also, I will be reusing that merge, it is parameterized by a `LabeldButton` (with `button_imageview_src` and `label_textview_text`). A `ButtonBar` can `include` an arbitrary number of `LabeldButton`'s.

Comment: @pskink However, the explicit `include` in the `LabeledButton`'s layout requires it to exist in every other `LabeledButton` layout definition (Add Button, Edit Button, ...). The trade off for having a more verbose layout file is worth it, they are much more readable and maintainable. Also, a single `include` line is much less copy-and-pasted code than if the merge contents were dropped directly into the layout (a third option). If there was a significant performance hit, then I would not use it.